# "Sign In to iTunes Store" dialog pops up even before I start my payment in StoreKit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

When I try to move to a view controller that uses StoreKit and In-App Purchase, it automatically pops up a *"Sign In to iTunes Store"* dialog to advance to In-App Purchase, despite me not starting my payment yet. What is causing this pop-up?

Xcode doesn't put any logs related to the dialog. How can I disable the dialog?

I used my Test Account to test my In-App Purchase. I first signed out of the account. Then I reran my app to confirm my purchase again, but it continuously displays the dialog with the test account even though I already signed out of the account. I don't understand why it still keeps using the signed-out account.

So what's the exact method that displays the dialog? I erased the app from my iPhone and reran the app but it still continues to pop up the dialog...

Or can the test account not be used anymore since I used it once?

#### UPDATE

Sorry for that this question has not been resolved for months, and because I had already replaced it with new iPhone, the pop-up isn't annoying me and I cannot reproduce the problem any longer...

Comment: Please share some code of In app purchase.

Comment: Are you sure you have completed all previous transactions?

Comment: Arpit, sorry I've already deleted those code... Wain, I got that it's highly likely that I forgot to call `finishTransaction:` in `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` status, but is it still feasible to finish the transaction after I changed the code and reran the app? Or do I have to create another Test User to test my in-app purchase?

Comment: I just added the new Test Account and signed out of the current iTunes account (so not sign-in to iTunes in any accounts), and started my app, but it still displays the dialog... So the dialog cannot be erased any more in my iPhone I think...

Answer (score 2):

Try to launch your app one time with code like this:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the above, and nothing helped, here is what I've tried and this one solved it for good (!):

1. Delete this sandbox user. (after that the popup with the old erased Apple ID still shows up!)
2. Restore all transactions:         SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
3. For each restored transaction:
   3.1. If no download content available, then just finish the transaction.
   3.2. If download content is available, then download and clean, and then finish the transaction.
   SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)

From some reason it didn't work for me if I didn't download the content before finishing the transaction.

Comment: I didn't need to delete the sandbox user, but restoring and then finishing all the transactions did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a previous transaction issue, somewhere you should have

```
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

and implemented something like this.

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

}

If you're not handling the purchasing / unpurchased items by calling

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

in the switch above, you'll run into the store trying to complete every time it's initialised as they transactions are still in an incomplete state

Comment: Thanks but I'm talking about how to disable the dialog AFTER I forgot to complete those transactions. Now I know how to finish the transaction properly, but the dialog still pops up because I didn't remove the failed transactions...

Comment: They should still be in this array. Anything that isn't finished must be in the payment queue?